# Generating locations based on a power-law distribution of distance from their origin

Tags: performance, matlab

I have a small function that gets a vector of *N* linear indices locations in a matrix and returns *N* new locations in the same matrix. For each of the input locations, a random angle *tet* and a distance *d* from a power-law distribution are randomized. The new *i*<sup>th</sup> location is the cell on the matrix that is in distance *d(i)* in direction *tet(i)* from the *i*<sup>th</sup> input location. The matrix represents a torus map, so if the new location is out of the matrix boundaries, it flows back from the other side.

This function is a part of a much larger program that simulates ecological community. It is called hundreds of millions of times and it is the slowest part (by far) in the program, taking about 10 times more than the next slowest operation.

I have tried the following:

1. Convert it to a MEX file
2. Casting all variables to the minimum size (i.e. uintX instead of double)
3. Using the built-in [`GeneralizedParetoDistribution`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.generalizedparetodistribution.html) to make a PDF object for the randomization

None of them reduced execution time, all of them did the opposite. Also, I cannot use parallel computing as I already use it at a 'higher' level of the program.
**I'll be glad for any advice/idea that will make this run faster.**
Thanks.

### EDIT

Thanks to several advise from @Cris Luengo I was able to cut some runtime:

1. I use another random generator called 'simdTwister' which is apparently significantly faster than the default 'twister'.

[image: gen compare]

2. I have changed the modulo conversion so I won't have to index and find the zero values after it.
3. I use a predefined list of values from power-law distribution to avoid the power computation on every run.

All other ideas within the comments and the answer was slower than the original code.

**This may look like an answer to the question, but it isn't.** The reason I'm still puzzled about it is that when I implement the third part (using a list of distances) in my outer function and use it in within (part) of the full program, it suddenly takes longer with this pre-computed list then without it, although I compute the list only once for all runs. I have checked this in different ways and have no idea why it is so. **Please let me know if there is something wrong (or inefficient) with the way I implement part 3 in the code below**.
Also, I would like to know if there is a way to randomize numbers from a 2D Pareto distribution, so I can avoid randomizing angles and converting them.

I have updated the code below to reflect this changes.

### CODE

Here is the function code:

```
function [destinations] = randisp_so(Origins,L,alpha,distances)
% select random direction with a distance from power-law distribution and
% convert back to vectorized form of the matrix
%
% ORIGINS is a list of origin cells
% L is the size of one side of the map
% ALPHA is the scale parameter of the distribution
% The destinations vector is the same size as ORIGINS

OriginSize = numel(Origins);
maxd = floor(sqrt(2)*L/2); % maximum distance for dispersal

% converting vetorized represatation to matrix:
c = ceil(double(Origins)./L); % ind2sub(q) - columns
r = double(Origins)-(c-1).*L; % ind2sub(q) - rows

if nargin==4
    % choose random length from a given distribution (as array):
    distance = maxd.*distances(randi(numel(distances),OriginSize,1));
else
    % List of distances to disperse from power-law distribution:
    e = (-1./(alpha-1));
    RND = (1-rand(OriginSize,1));
    distance = maxd.*RND.^e;
end

% choose a random angle from uniform distribution [0 2*pi]
angles = rand(OriginSize,1)*2*pi;

new_r = round(r + distance.*cos(angles)); % convert length to cell row
new_c = round(c + distance.*sin(angles)); % convert length to cell column

% transform rows and columns to a 'close-map'
new_r = mod(new_r-1,L)+1;
new_c = mod(new_c-1,L)+1;

% convert back to vectotized form:
destinations = new_r+(new_c-1).*L; %sub2ind(r,c);
end
```

And a little testbench for running this function:

```
% randisp_so testbench
n = 10;
L = 2^n+1; % the size of one side of the map
MapSize = L^2; % total number of cells in the map
N = MapSize*30;
alpha = 0.7;
rng('shuffle','simdTwister') % the fastest random generator
q = uint32(randi(MapSize,N,1));
% List of distances to disperse from power-law distribution:
distances = linspace(1,0,MapSize).^(-1./(alpha-1)).';

timeit(@() randisp_so(q,L,alpha)) % 2.5153 sec
timeit(@() randisp_so(q,L,alpha,distances)) % 1.9008 sec
```

And here is a comparison of the profile of a typical run:

[image: profile compare]

Comment: Any specific reason you convert `q` to uint32, and back to doubles within your function? Other than that I don't see any obvious weird things. You could pre-compute `cos` and `sin`, I'm sure you don't need very high precision. The power is also expensive to compute. Interpolating into tables for those could save a lot of time.

Comment: I have a hard time believing the MEX version is slower. How did you convert? Is there an automated conversion? A hand-written C function is likely to be faster, but not necessarily by much.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @CrisLuengo, I actually tried to create a table of distances to perform the power only once per simulation, but it turns out to be a little bit slower somehow. I'll try that for both power and the trigonometric functions, and see if it helps. As for MEX, I use the automatic code generation in Matlab, so it's probably less efficient than a native C code, but I don't write C regularly and have no time to make sure it will work as expected. However, I'm not surprised by that Mex taking longer, since I use only built-in functions, that are already written at a lower level...

Comment: ... and Mex impose a lot of unnecessary variable validations and communication between Matlab and C, which slowing things up. This is a well-known problem with using MEX (I can't find a good reference for that right now).

Comment: And, as for converting to uint32 - this is related to the outer program, where I use large vectors and save them, so in order to facilitate operations on them, I use uint32. This function is the only case where I need the double precision. Also, I find that the slowest part is usually generating random numbers (which is needed even if I prepare tables of distances before), so maybe there is a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the automatically generated MEX code executes the exact same functions as the M-file code. I think there would be a little benefit to writing a hand-coded loop in C, but not a whole lot. You could save all the parameter validation in each of those function calls, and if your array is sufficiently large, a single loop that computes everything per element rather than all these functions with their own loops could be quite a bit faster. But you need to be able to maintain it for it to be worth while.

Comment: If the random number generator is slow, you could try using a different one. By default MATLAB uses the Marsenne Twister, which is not known as a fast option... The [`rng`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) function lets you pick the generator. There is a "SIMD-oriented Fast Mersenne Twister", as well as a few different RNGs. I don't know about the quality of their randomness.

Comment: Profiling MATLAB drives me nuts. :) I repeated your profiling to see actual times, because your results were so weird. I see something similar. Computing the distances takes 0.81s, reading them from a table takes 1.26s. But when reading from a table everything else is so much cheaper... even computing random angles goes from 0.38s to 0.18s. How is that even possible???

Comment: OK, some of the timing differences in the profiler are because I just ran the function once. There's a lot of variability. But I did find the reason for the difference in timings of the `mod` calls. It seems that it doesn't do a division if the input value is already within the range, the more values are outside the range, the longer the call takes. When you do `distance = RND.^e;` you compute values many orders of magnitude larger than `maxd`. (continued)

Comment: (continued) I changed your code to `RND = 1-rand(OriginSize,1); distance = maxd.*(RND.^e);`, yielding the same distribution of distances as with the lookup table, and cut execution time in half (making it 10% faster than the other method on my system). But you can also reduce the size of the table for good speed gains. I think `L^2*30` is too large -- a table with 31M entries to find a random distance between 0 and 724 (which will be rounded to an integer location anyway). I tried with `L*30` instead, reduced time from 2.2s to 1.8s. But do check you get the right distribution!!!

Comment: @CrisLuengo, sorry for the bother, but this was just a mistake. The original line was `distance = maxd.*(1-rand(OriginSize,n)).^(-1./(k-1));` which is equivalent to what you wrote. When written like this the `mod` operation is not significantly slower. As for making the distance list shorter - I actually do use a shorter list, but that doesn't seem to matter, the timing is not affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code again, there are a few things that you could try:

## 1. Avoid trigonometric functions

These seem to be the most expensive part of your code. You compute a single uniformly distributed random value, turn it into a random angle, then get coordinates on the circle from that:

```
angles = rand(qSize,1)*2*pi;
new_r = r + ceil(distance.*cos(angles)); % convert length to cell row
new_c = c + ceil(distance.*sin(angles)); % convert length to cell column
```

Instead you could compute two normally distributed values, and normalize the vector:

```
pos = randn(n,2);
new_coords = coords + ceil(distance(pos ./ sqrt(sum(pos.^2,2)));
```

(with `coords` would be equivalent to `[c,r]` for simplicity here).

The 2D normal distribution is isotropic, this leads to exactly the same probability distribution.

In my test this was only about 10% faster, but every bit counts, right? `randn` is more expensive than `rand`, and there's the `sqrt` as well.

Ideally there would be a way to convert the Gaussian distribution into the power law distribution. This would avoid normalizing `pos`, and then sampling another random value for the distance. I don't know if this is possible, or how costly it would be.

## 2. Modulo operation

I'm surprised by the cost of the modulo operation. But it makes sense, it's a floating-point operation. Your coordinates never extend past the end of the matrix by a whole lot. You could instead try comparisons:

```
% original code
new_r = mod(new_r,A)+1;

% alternative
I = new_r>A;
new_r(I) = new_r(I)-A;
I = new_r<1;
new_r(I) = new_r(I)+A;
```

This is actually slower in Octave, but it's possible that MATLAB does a better job at optimizing these indexing operations. Worth a try in any case. An alternative to `mod` is `rem`, but I don't think either is faster than the other.

Note that your original code is biased: you always add 1 to the index. This causes your movement to be biased by 1 to the right and bottom of the matrix. To be correct it would have to be:

```
new_r = mod(new_r-1,A)+1;
```

The other bias in your code is the use of `ceil` instead of `round` when you initially compute the coordinates. This causes your movement to be biased by an additional 0.5 to the right and bottom of the matrix. I recommend that you plot the output of `randisp_so` for a thousand points, all in the same position in the matrix. Make sure that the output positions are distributed isotropically around that point!

**Edit:**

This function is about 30% faster than `mod` (sorry for the poor variable names):

```
function v = fast_modulo(v,A)
persistent X;
if numel(X)~=3*A
   X = repmat(1:A,1,3);
end
v = X(v+A);
```

You'd call

```
new_r = fast_modulo(new_r,A);
new_c = fast_modulo(new_c,A);
```

The function expects integer inputs that are not too far outside of the `1:A` range (should be OK in your application). As long as you call this function with the same A, it doesn't need to recompute `X`.

## 3. Prevent conversion linear index from coordinates

This is not the most expensive part of your code, but it seems illogical to me. You could pass coordinates to/from your function:

```
[destenations,coords] = randisp_so(coords,A,alpha)
```

The calling function would use `destenations` (I presume), and store `coords` for the next iteration. `coords` would be equivalent to `[c,r]`.

BTW: did you notice that `destenations` is a typo? It's hard to type for me! :)

Comment: Many thank for the answer, I'll take a closer look at the relevant parts, especially at part 1. As for your suggestions in parts 2&3, here are some relevant comments: 1. Modulo operation turns out to be [slower also in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723059/how-do-i-make-modulo-and-logical-indexing-work-faster); 2. You are right about the bias problem, I have already noticed it and changed my code properly, though, in a slightly different way, I'll try your correction for the modulo operation; ...

Comment: @EBH, I've edited part 2, I was thinking about a faster alternative to `mod`, I couldn't let go. :)

Comment: 3. The calling function use only linear indexing and store all the data in a vectorized from to [speed things up](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~marios/matlab/Writing_Fast_MATLAB_Code.pdf). If I take your suggestion about `coords` I'll have to convert `q` to subscripts every time before calling the function and convert `destinations` back to linear. I had no time to continue working on this function lately, but a soon as I'll get back to it I'll update the question with further information.

Comment: The idea in part 1 looks like an interesting new direction, and I'll also test your new suggestion for `fast_modulo`. Stay tuned ;)

Comment: And thanks for the typo correction (corrected in question), I'm not a native English speaker so that isn't hard for me...

Comment: First reports: using 2D normal distribution was slower than trigonometric functions (maybe because it requires generating X2 random numbers); `fast_modulo` was slower than simple modulo, but your correction for the bias in that line was faster than mine; The only change that made a significant difference so far was setting the random generator to 'simdTwister'. I'll add more details with the update to the question.

Comment: Sorry none of my ideas helped. Thanks for the feedback though! Timing differences are interesting though. It seems you get different results than I did. Probably problem size dependent. Maybe MATLAB version dependent, CPU dependent, and who knows what else.

Comment: Some of your ideas (even if not the boldest ones) were helpful indeed. I have edited the question to reflect my current status. I still wonder if there's a way to randomize a value from a 2D Pareto distribution so I won't have to randomize angles and convert them. **Many thanks for all the effort** I learned some new things, and grateful for your ideas. I'll leave this question open for a while, and if no one will come up with some new ideas (or I'll finish my PhD...) I'll accept it.